# Any great commentary of "On Sense and Nominatum" by Frege?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, frege

I'm reading it and I feel that I sometimes I need some level of context. Thanks.

Comment: Almost any introduction to the philosophy of language will start with that paper, it is one of the most foundational papers in analytic philosophy. Try the [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/) and the [IEP](https://www.iep.utm.edu/freg-lan/) for context.

Answer (score 3):

- Mark Textor, [Routledge Philosophy GuideBook to Frege on Sense and Reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=YwXHBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2010).
- Wolfgang Carl, [Frege's Theory of Sense and Reference: Its Origin and Scope](https://books.google.it/books?id=exU6CUyTxO8C&printsec=frontcover) (1994).
- Kevin Klement, [Frege and the Logic of Sense and Reference](https://books.google.it/books?id=Lskw6AYQHIoC&printsec=frontcover) (2002).